# Code from scratch an image cropper AND resizer (at same time) in jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-plugins, web

We are coding a rather simple Javascript (jQuery) image cropper & resizer. Basically, for now, only features needed are indeed **crop** and **resize**.

I have been checking a few jQuery plugins like JCrop etc. and it seems there's no plugins doing ***both*** things at same time. Lots of croppers **OR** resizer, but not the two features on a same "natural" image view at same time. By natural I mean that examples like this (bottom right) are not very nice visually for users :

http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/74Jep/33/

Although I guess this would be a possible way to go to have the two features at same time. Though you can see this example only zooms too currently and it is qualified as using *"ugly hacks"* by the author himself to do so :

```
function changeZoom(percent){
    var minWidth=viewport.width();
    var newWidth= (orgWidth-minWidth)*percent/100+minWidth;
    var newHeight= newWidth/orgRatio;
    var oldSize=[img.width(),img.height()];

    img.css({ width: newWidth+"px", height: newHeight+"px" });

    adjustDimensions();

    //ugly hack :(
    if (img.offset().left+img.width()>dragcontainer.offset().left+dragcontainer.width()){
        img.css({ left: dragcontainer.width()-img.width() +"px" });  
    }
    if (img.offset().top+img.height()>dragcontainer.offset().top+dragcontainer.height()){
        img.css({ top: dragcontainer.height()-img.height() +"px" });  
    } 
}
```

We are rather looking for the possibilty to use a cropper frame/zone (as we see the most often on the web) + a zoom/de-zoom option on the image (handles on the border of the image for example)

Since we only need those two features we thought we would code this from scratch or almost as we don't want to add other javascript files/plugins which will be overkill anyway being packed with other features we will not need (at least for now).

**The question is:** is there a specific difficulty at trying to code the display of an image re-sizable by straightforward handles & croppable by a frame/zone selection (which would also be re-sizable on its own and draggable around so a user can fine tune which part of the image he wants)?

Are we definitely better separating the two features ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is there a specific browser your fiddle needs to be viewed in?

Comment: @Asad not that I am aware of.. I've been using Firefox 16 and it seems to work as expected on Chrome too...

Comment: I think he means who are you making this for? For example, if you're targeting the general public, you'll have to deal with IE too.

Comment: Aww... Well then no, @Asad we can ask specifically for the use of Firefox or Chrome for example as it's kind of a admin feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this plugin??

http://code.google.com/p/resize-crop/

It does both crop and resize